# How to point CNAME to a hostname using terraform

Tags: dns, terraform, cname, linode

I am adding a CNAME record using terraform and I want to point it to hostname I created using terraform on linode.

This is my **main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    linode = {
      source = "linode/linode"
      version = "1.16.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "linode" {
    token = "some_secret_token"
}

resource "linode_instance" "example_instance" {
    label = "example_instance_ubuntu-eu-west"
    image = "linode/ubuntu20.04"
    region = "eu-west"
    type = "g6-nanode-1"
    root_pass = "testing@linode"
}

resource "linode_domain" "example_domain" {
  domain   = "example.mydomain.com"
  soa_email= "my@email.com"
  type     = "master"
}

resource "linode_domain_record" "example_domain_record" {
  domain_id  =  linode_domain.example_domain.id
  name       = "example.mydomain.com"
  record_type= "CNAME"
  target     = linode_instance.example_instance.label
  ttl_sec    = 300
}
```

`terrafomr plan` results in

linode_domain.example_domain: Refreshing state... [id=1753447]
linode_instance.example_instance: Refreshing state... [id=33094611]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:

- create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

```
  # linode_domain_record.example_domain_record will be created
  + resource "linode_domain_record" "example_domain_record" {
      + domain_id   = 1753447
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "example.mydomain.com"
      + record_type = "CNAME"
      + target      = "example_instance_ubuntu-eu-west"
      + ttl_sec     = 300
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

But `terraform apply` errors:

```
linode_domain_record.example_domain_record: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating a Linode DomainRecord: [400] [target] You have entered an invalid target. It must be a valid hostname.; [name] Invalid hostname 
│ 
│   with linode_domain_record.example_domain_record,
│   on main.tf line 28, in resource "linode_domain_record" "example_domain_record":
│   28: resource "linode_domain_record" "example_domain_record" {
│ 
╵
```

but `example_instance_ubuntu-eu-west` does exist in the my linodes

Comment: As the error states, a Linode instance label is not a hostname, so I'm not sure how you expect this to work. Looking at the documentation it appears that the Linode Terraform provider only gives you the instance IP address, not the hostname. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/linode/linode/latest/docs/resources/instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @mark-b's comment, you may want to consider using an `A`(ddress) record type rather than `CNAME` to reference the linode.

As long as the Linode has an accessible public IPv4 address (replace `ADDR` below with the linode's public IP), you can:

```
resource "linode_domain_record" "example_domain_record" {
  domain_id  =  linode_domain.example_domain.id
  name       = "example.mydomain.com"
  record_type= "A"
  target     = ADDR
  ttl_sec    = 300
}
```

See: [`linode_domain_record`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/linode/linode/latest/docs/resources/domain_record) and specifically the documentation for [record_type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/linode/linode/latest/docs/resources/domain_record#record_type)

> It's unlikely but if the instance has an IPv6 address then you'll want to use `AAAA`